# FileStream success over HTTP, Fails on HTTPS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

The code is a simple web API action which streams the file back as an attachment.

Server: (Web API Controller action) (type: HttpResponseMessage)

```
  [path fetching code earlier on]
  ...
  var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
  var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
  result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
  result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
  result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
  result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
  result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;

  return result
```

If I make the request in Chrome, the server side executes fine in HTTP mode and returns my file. Everything works as expected...

**However** If I do this over **HTTPS**, the server side completes and then the UI hangs downloading the file until it eventaully times out with chrome outputting:

```
GET https://localhost/mysite/api/GetFile?file=ABC net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to enable something else to do this over HTTPS/SSL?

*Notes; The file is only about 50k so it's not a size thing.*

Comment: Hitting other controller actions over SSL works as expected?

Comment: Yes. All the other actions complete as expected,

Comment: What error do you see if you hit it in another browser or fiddler? I find the chrome error screen less than helpful and the others sometimes give better info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

It looks like this error was being caused by removing:

```
result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
```

Removing this fixed this. Not sure why it works over HTTP and not HTTPS though.